# Transferring data to another controller with segue. From the code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, storyboard

How to pass values ​​from one controller to another??? I use a StoryBoard.

[image: storyboard]

I would like this to appear on the highlighted text view of the first view.

Call the next view of the code, I think something like this should look like:

```
UIStoryboard *finish = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

    UIViewController *viewController = [finish instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FinishController"];

     viewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet;
     [self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

finishcontroller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.lblFinishTitle.text=self.FinishTitle;
    self.lblFinishDesc.text = self.FinishDesc;
    self.lblFinishPoint.text=self.FinishPoint;
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

first view:

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier hasPrefix:@"FinishController"]) {
        FinishController *asker = (FinishController *) segue.destinationViewController;
        asker.FinishDesc = @"What do you want your label to say?";
        asker.FinishTitle = @"Label text";
        asker.FinishPoint = @"asdas";
    }
}
```

I want to pass a value causing the transmission of the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you aren't actually using that segue, you are using `presentModalController` instead.

Note that usually, you can just ask `self` for it's storyboard. However, even that is unnecessary when you have a segues connected:

```
[self preformSegueWithIdentifier:@"FinishController" sender:self];
```

Then prepareForSegue *will* be called. Also note that you can (should) use something more authoritative than the segue identifier to determine if you should load the data... you can ask the segue's destination controller if it is the right class:

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[FinishController class]]) {
        FinishController *asker = (FinishController *) segue.destinationViewController;
        asker.FinishDesc = @"What do you want your label to say?";
        asker.FinishTitle = @"Label text";
        asker.FinishPoint = @"asdas";
    }
}
```

You are probably already aware (since you used the identifier in your code), but for the benefit of future discoverers of this post; segues are given identifiers in the inspector panel of Xcode when you are in the storyboard.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I realized the error but when I use: "[self preformSegueWithIdentifier: @" FinishController "];", I get an error: "No visible @interface for 'ViewController' declares the selector 'preformSegueWithIdentifier:'"

Comment: Sorry, I left out part of the method signature... it takes a second parameter (sender), which you usually pass as the thing that "caused" the segue to occur (a button, for instance... however buttons can be directly connected to segues in the storyboard). http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW83

Comment: [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Finish" sender:self]; used! and all is well! Thank you very much!