# ios changing class of view controller

Tags: ios

I have few buttons in main view controller. Using storyboards, I desire to segue from two of those buttons to the same tab bar controller and depending on which button is pushed to change the class of one of view controllers of given tab bar controller.

Is it possible? Appreciate any advice.

Comment: You mean to say that you want to call a tabbar controller having two tabs from ViewController.On click on button 1 in viewcontroller it will call Tab1 in tabbar and On click on button 2 in viewcontroller it will call Tab2 in tabbar.Am I right?

Comment: No, On click button1 and button2 it should call the same Tab1 , but depending on button to change the class of Tab1 .

Comment: ok, basically Tab1 have 2 different view which will get load depending on the clicked button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of **prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender** in the controller where you have define the buttons in order to send information to the destination controller.

> See for detail : https://stackoverflow.com/a/11464268/1749367

Answer (score 0):

In Storyboard connect your `ViewController` with the `TabBarController` add your respective tabs to `TabBarController`

Add two buttons in viewController in Storyboard add assign tags to them 1 and 2 respectively.

In viewController.m

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
 UIButton *mybutton = (UIButton *)sender;
 if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"tabbar"]) 
    {
      UITabBarController *tabbar = segue.destinationViewController;

      UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

      if(myButton.tag == 0)
      {
      UIViewController  *tab1 = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tab1"];
      }
      else
      {
      UIViewController  *tab1 = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tab2"];
      }


      UIViewController  *otherTab= [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Othertab"];


    tabbar.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:tab1,othertab, nil];
}
}
```